# How to update more than one state in a Localstorage object React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks, local-storage

So I already have a localStorage hook that persist the state but now I want to update two items in the object

This here is the function that adds the update

```
  const { data, setData } = useLocalStorage();

  const addWorkExperience = () => {
    let additionJob = {
      ...data,
      jobExperience: [
        ...data.jobExperience,
        {
          city: "",
          company: "",
          country: "",
          current: false,
          endMonth: "",
          endYear: "",
          jobTitle: "",
          startMonth: "",
          startYear: "",
          state: "",
          workDesc: "",
        },
      ],
      currentEditedJob: data.currentEditedJob + 1,
    };

    setData(additionJob, console.log(additionJob, data));
```

when it is logged it brings the jobExperience array like this `jobExperience: (6) ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', {…}]` Only one object is saved and the rest are turned into numbers

I noticed that if I removed `currentEditedJob: data.currentEditedJob + 1,` from the additional job object everything works fine and the states updates well and they are saved as object `jobExperience: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Is there a solution around this please

I tried update the states one by one by it didn't work as well.

```
    setTemplateData((prev) => ({...prev,
        jobExperience: [
           ...prev.jobExperience,
           {
             city: "",
             company: "",
             country: "",
             current: false,
             endMonth: "",
             endYear: "",
             jobTitle: "",
             startMonth: "",
             startYear: "",
             state: "",
             workDesc: "",
          },
        ],
       currentEditedJob: data.currentEditedJob + 1,
     }), console.log(additionJob, data));
```

But it was still the same bug unless I remove `currentEditedJob: data.currentEditedJob + 1,`

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the issue lies with the currentEditedJob property in your addWorkExperience function. Based on the code you provided, it appears that data.currentEditedJob is a string representation of a number, and when you add 1 to it, it concatenates the number instead of performing arithmetic addition.

To resolve this, you can convert data.currentEditedJob to a number before adding 1 to it. Here's an updated version of your addWorkExperience function:

```
  const currentEditedJob = parseInt(data.currentEditedJob, 10); // Convert to number
  const additionJob = {
    ...data,
    jobExperience: [
      ...data.jobExperience,
      {
        city: "",
        company: "",
        country: "",
        current: false,
        endMonth: "",
        endYear: "",
        jobTitle: "",
        startMonth: "",
        startYear: "",
        state: "",
        workDesc: "",
      },
    ],
    currentEditedJob: currentEditedJob + 1, // Perform arithmetic addition
  };

  setData(additionJob);
  console.log(additionJob, data);
};
```

By converting data.currentEditedJob to a number using parseInt(), the addition operation will work correctly, and the state will be updated as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: The currentEditedJob property is another property separate from the jobExperience property, The currentEditedJob property updates fine regardless but it's the jobExperience property that get disturbed whenever the currentEditedJob is updated

Comment: If I stored them as two seperate object in the localStorage they work absolutely fine, but they dont seem to work fine when they are a objects in one object in the local storage